# Reading headers from JSON file and setting as tuples for Header in API Call using Play in SCALA

Tags: json, scala, playframework-2.0

Reading headers from JSON file and setting as tuples for Header in API Call using Play in SCALA

I have Json file which have headers and body like this:
File name: test.json

```
{
    "request": {
    "headers" : {
            "Provider":"1122321",
            "Authorization":"44444444",
            "Agent":"Web",
            "Content-Type":"application/json"
          }
     "body":{
    }
    }
    }
```

Now what I am trying to do is, reading Body and Headers from Json file and using later in making a call to API, I am using play WS and Play JSON (2.5.x) for this, but I am unable to get and set headers:

Below is my code,currently I have hard-coded headers, but I need to get and set from JSON, one way I tried is to add headers in List of tuple and use, but I am unable to figure our how I can get headers from JSON file and convert them to list of tuple

```
val file = new File("E:\\test.json")
val fileIn = new FileInputStream(file)
val json: JsValue = Json.parse(fileIn)
val jsonbody = (json \ "data" \ "request" \"body").get
val jsonheader = (json \ "data" \ "request" \"headers").get
println(jsonheader)   
// {"Provider":"1122321","Authorization":"44444444","Agent":"Web","Content-Type":"application/json"}

var url: String = "http://test.com/api/test"

// wsClient.url(url2).withHeaders("Provider"->"1122321", "Authorization" ->` "44444444", "Agent" -> "Web", "Content-Type" -> "application/json", "ClientVersion" -> "3").post(jsonbody).map { response =>
  val resbody1: String = response.body
  val resstatus1: String = response.statusText

}
```

Comment: Using `.get` on `JsResult` (as on `Option`) is a code smell. Why don't you "map" case class with JSON and then work with instances of such case class? https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ScalaJson

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out, but currently my issue to get headers from JSON file and make a HTTP call

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to achieve what I was trying for, but I know it's not an efficient way, if anyone can help me improve this will be much appreciated:

```
val file = new File("E:\\test.json")
val fileIn = new FileInputStream(file)
val json: JsValue = Json.parse(fileIn)
val jsonbody = (json \ "data" \ "request" \"body").get
val jsonheader = (json \ "data" \ "request" \"headers").get
println(jsonheader)   
// {"Provider":"1122321","Authorization":"44444444","Agent":"Web","Content-Type":"application/json"}

 val jsonheaderlist = jsonheader.toString().substring(1, jsonfile.headersval.toString().length - 1)
      .split(",")
      .map(_.split(":"))
      .map { case Array(k, v) => (k.substring(1, k.length-1), v.substring(1, v.length-1))}
      .toMap.toList

var url: String = "http://test.com/api/test"

var req = wsClient.url(url)
jsonheaderlist.foreach{case(value)=>
    req = req.withHeaders(value)
    }
req = req.post(jsonbody).map { response =>
  val resbody1: String = response.body
  val resstatus1: String = response.statusText

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to cast your JSON to `JsObject` instead of `JsValue`
As cchantep said, it is easier to do with a case class :

```
case class Request(headers:JsObject, body:JsObject)
object Request {
   implicit lazy val format = Json.format[Request]
}
```

And inside your code you can map your Json like this :

```
val file = new File("E:\\test.json")
val fileIn = new FileInputStream(file)
val json: JsValue = Json.parse(fileIn)
val req = (json \ "request").as[Request]
```

The list of tuples is now accessible with the 'fields' attribute :

```
val tuples:Seq[(String, JsValue)] = req.fields
val headers:Map[String, String] = tuples.map{ header =>
  header._1 -> header._2.as[String]
}.toMap
```

Comment: That's not a cast (which is unsafe) there, but a JSON validation as

Comment: Thanks for your comment, as I am new to Scala, I am not very good with case, but I like you idea for create and a case and than getting value as per that case